# Regular Expression All strings where the number of b’s can be evenly divided by 3

Tags: automata, finite-automata, automata-theory

I am a student doing assigment can any tell me the solution for numbers of bs evenly divided by 3.Have already checked stackover flow no such question i found.

Comment: Please include sample data along with whatever you have already tried.  Note that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: accully there is no sample that i have to just Write Regular expression which contain number of b,s that can be evenly divided by 3.

Comment: Try: `^(?:[^b]*b[^b]*b[^b]*b[^b]*)*$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, all languages are sets of strings whose symbols are taken from some alphabet. You mention just one symbol, b. Your alphabet may be {b}. Or, maybe your strings can also have a; then your alphabet is {a, b}. I'll assume the latter for this answer since it's the harder case to answer and is more representative of all other possible cases.

We make a few observations:

1. the empty string is in the language
2. you can always add more instances of a anywhere
3. you can only add more instances of b in multiples of three

The simplest string with three instances of b is bbb. However, as a regular expression, this restricts us to just contiguous instances of b. We want to be able to add instances of a anywhere; so consider

```
a*ba* ba*ba*
```

This regular expression gives us just the strings with exactly three instances of b. To allow any number, we can use a Kleene star and add some more a*:

```
a*(a*ba*ba*ba*)*a*
```